# Can erc20 type in erc1155 be listed on uniswap or exchanges?

Tags: solidity, erc1155

An example from Alchemy,

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";

contract AwesomeGame is ERC1155 {
    uint256 public constant GOLD = 0;
    uint256 public constant SWORD = 1;
    uint256 public constant CROWN = 2;

    constructor() ERC1155("https://awesomegame.com/assets/{id}.json") {
        _mint(msg.sender, GOLD, 10**18, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, SWORD, 1000, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, CROWN, 1, "");
    }
}
```

Here, `GOLD` is an erc20 type and just wondering if it can have some monetary value like erc20 and be listed on uniswap or exchanges? and two side questions,

`_mint(msg.sender, GOLD, 10**18, "");`

1. is this minting only 1 token?
2. is `SWORD` still NFT? I think it's fungible with 1k quantity and it should not be non-fungible token (NFT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand [why ERC-1155 was introduced](https://blog.enjincoin.io/erc-1155-the-crypto-item-standard-ac9cf1c5a226) in the first place. In short, it was introduced to cater to the need for in-game currency and items.

1. Yes it will but why would you be needing that many decimals for GOLD? I've seen people setting 4 at max.
2. 2. As per [ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-1155/#nft_support), If the supply is only 1, treat it as NFT.

and to answer your main question No you can't add it. You can see more detail discussion on [forum.openzeppelin](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/can-erc1155-tokens-be-put-onto-uniswap/5235/3).